# How to draw a rhombus, where the angle of the sloping side is user-defined, using Google Drawings

Tags: google-drawings

I'm trying to draw a rhombus using Google Drawings. I start by selecting the parallelogram shape, then draw it with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down. This creates a rhombus, but with the angle of the sloping side pre-defined at around 75 degrees. I'd like it to be around 30 degrees. If I click on the small yellow diamond - top left corner of the rhombus - and drag to the right, I can reduce the slope but I no longer have a rhombus.

I've found a way round this problem. I can create a rhombus using four straight lines, all of the same length, however, when I group the resulting image it doesn't form a Google shape, i.e. I can't set a fill colour. What I do next is to select Polyline and use it to copy my rhombus created from four separate lines. The rhombus created using Polyline does seem to be a 'proper' Google shape and I can control the fill colour.

It works, but I'd love to think there is an easier way to achieve such a simple end result.